# Python exe built using Pyinstaller does not run on all the machines as it does not have the necessary MS certificates

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have built an exe on python to run on various machines in my office, but it does not run as the system finds it less secured. Some of the antivirus even quarantine it.

Is there a way to build exe with all the necessary security so that it behaves like a normal exe.

Do we need to add any certificate for it to run normal ?